# How to generate callback for buttons in box grouping container in Custom UI Editor?

Tags: excel, ribbonx

I am creating a custom toolbar for Excel 2010 and I am running into an problem with 2 of the buttons I have placed in a box group.  For some reason they are not generating callbacks from the "onAction" command like all my others are and I am not getting any coding errors.  I have been going through the markup specifications but cannot find a command that might work.  Anyone see what I am doing wrong?  The box group I am referring to is at the bottom of the code below - buttons labeled "ConvertToValues" and "TrimSpaces".  Thanks.

```html
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
<tabs>
 <tab id="MyCustomTab" label="Reporting">
  <group id="AvtGroup" label="Actual v Target">
   <button id="AvTDataPrep"
    label="Data Organization"
    imageMso="CreateQueryInDesignView"
    size="large"
    onAction="PrepAvTData" />
   <button id="ChannelExport"
    label="Channel Analysis Export"
    imageMso="TableExportTableToSharePointList"
    size="large"
    onAction="ExportChannelData" />
   <button id="Top50Export"
    label="Top 50 Export"
    imageMso="TableExportTableToSharePointList"
    size="large"
    onAction="ExportTop50Data" />
   <button id="Top50CopyPaste"
    label="Top 50 Copy/Paste"
    imageMso="ImportExcel"
    size="large"
    onAction="CopyandPasteTop50Data" />
  </group>
  <group id="RMbyLocGroup" label="Route Metrics by Location">
   <button id="RMDataPrep"
    label="Data Organization"
    imageMso="CreateQueryInDesignView"
    size="large"
    onAction="PrepRMData" />
  </group>
  <group id="ServiceMetricsGroup1" label="Service Metrics Tools">
   <button id="FrequencyUpdate"
    label="Frequency Update (AvT File)"
    imageMso="PivotTableFormulasMenu"
    size="large"
    onAction="UpdateFrequencies" />
   <button id="ServiceMetrics"
    label="Service Metrics (AvT File)"
    imageMso="DatasheetNewField"
    size="large"
    onAction="AddServiceMetrics" />
  </group>
  <group id="FormattingGroup" label="Formatting Tools">
   <box id="FormattingBox" boxStyle="vertical">
    <button id="ConvertToValues"
     label="Convert To Values"
     imageMso="ConditionalFormattingBottomNItems"
     onAction="ConvertToValues" />
    <button id="TrimSpaces"
     label="Trim Excess Spaces"
     imageMso="FormControlEditBox"
     onAction="TrimSpaces" />
   </box>
  </group>
 </tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the `Custom UI editor` is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-custom-ui-editor). You can get the latest version and run it under the debugger where you can find the answer why callbacks are not generated for controls grouped together under the box control.

As a workaround you may add ribbon callbacks manually.